# How to handle python packages with conflicting names?

Tags: python, namespaces, setuptools, alembic

I'm using two python packages that have the same name.

- http://www.alembic.io/updates.html
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alembic

Is there a canonical or pythonic way to handle installing two packages with conflicting names? So far, I've only occasionally needed one of the packages during development/building, so I've been using a separate virtualenv to deal with the conflict, but it makes the build step more complex and I wonder if there isn't a better way to handle it.

Comment: Virtualenv is the best way, i think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the --target option for pip and install to an alternate location:

```
pip install --target=/tmp/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alt_alembic alembic
```

Then when you import in python, do the first as usual and for the alt do an import from that namespace like this:

```
import alembic  # alembic.io version
from alt_alembic import alembic as alt_alembic  # pip version
```

Then when you're making calls to that one you can call alt_alembic.function() and to the one that isn't in PyPi, alembic.function()
My target path has /tmp/test as I was using a virtual env. You would need to replace that path with the correct one for your python installation.

Answer (score -2):

how about **absolute and relative imports.**

https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports

Comment: Using relative imports would handle internal **module** or **sub-package** conflicts with other top-level modules and packages, but it won't help when two top level packages are named the same.

Comment: then we should use virtualenv