# Newly installed package shadows my package

Tags: python, python-2.7, namespaces, pip

I have a local package `pyapp` which I make available in other packages like this:

```
$ ln -s ~/src/pyapp/pyapp ~/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Now this setup is broken becaise

```
$ pip install --upgrade $(pip list --outdated | cut -f1 -d" ")
```

installed something in `~/.virtualenvs/myvenv/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyapp` (note `lib64` vs `lib`).

Now I am getting errors like this:

```
File "blah.py" line....
  from pyapp.application import Application
ImportError: No module named application
```

**What is the solution?**

- Note that the `lib64` package was required by something else, so making my package shadow it is *not* an option.
- Renaming my package becomes a moving target (what if I rename it to `mypack1` and someone releases such a package and it is installed as a dependency?)
- What if I use packages `P1` (which depends on `D1`) and `P2` (which depends on `D2`) and the names of `D1` and `D2` are the same? [How to handle python packages with conflicting names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27532112/850781) helps only if both dependencies are installed by hand.

Comment: How about renaming your package?

Comment: @PauloScardine: this would mean changing all the places were I use it too, as well as renaming a git directory. I would rather avoid it. I would prefer to make a small change in the __init__ file(s), if possible.

Comment: I can think of a few hacks but the safe course is to rename your package. You are right, refactoring can be a pain without a good IDE - I use PyCharm from Jetbrains and it makes refactoring a non-issue.