# Resolve conflicting package names in Python

Tags: python, pythonpath, python-packaging

Let's say we have two different Python packages from the same vendor, named with the same name -- `foo`. One is installed with `pip` and can be found in the `/usr/lib/python/site-packages/foo` directory, the second one is a system-wide dependency which you install with e.g. `apt-get` and the Python package ends up in `/usr/lib/some-vendor-sdk/foo`. Local and global `foo` do different things and I need them both to be importable in my source code, but I can only import one:

```
$ python
>>> import foo
>>> foo.__path__
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo
```

Is there a way to make both packages importable in my code? It'd be fine to alias one of them somehow, I just don't know a technical way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the packages using absolute imports internally?

Comment: Maybe, this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532112/how-to-handle-python-packages-with-conflicting-names

Comment: So you have two different Python packages, from the same vendor, named with the same name and they do different things? slap that vendor

Comment: which is your python version?

Comment: How is the "_system-wide_" `foo` package (the one installed via _apt_) made importable in the Python interpreter? Does its parent directory somehow end up being added to `sys.path`? When only the "_system-wide_" one is installed, what is the value of `foo.__path__` then?