# Two pip-installed modules have the same name, how to select which one is loaded?

Tags: python, pip, python-module, pypi

I'm writing a python [program](https://github.com/bergamote/micronux) that relies on a specific module, `rtmidi`. Thing is, at least two different packages in PyPI have a module with that name, [rtmidi](https://pypi.org/project/rtmidi/) and [python-rtmidi](https://pypi.org/project/python-rtmidi/). They offer almost the same functionalities but have different syntax.

When only the "right" package is installed everything works fine. But if both packages are installed, using `import rtmidi` loads the "wrong" module and my program crashes. The only way to get it working again is to uninstall both packages then re-install the right one. Of course, since the user might rely on the other module for other programs, I can't expect them to do that.

Trying to identify the module with `rtmidi.__name__` gives the same result with both packages.

So my question, how do I go about resolving this name clash problem? Is there a best-practice way to handle this?

Comment: You can use `sys.path.insert` to prefer finding a package in one location rather than another, though I'm not sure if there is a platform-independent way to locate a specific package.

Comment: @mousetail Right, gonna look into this, but wouldn't that force every other program that rely on that module name to implement the same workaround, since both modules are installed?

Comment: Changing `sys.path` is global and will effect all packages imported after you changed it, even third-party modules

Comment: @mousetail My concern was for other programs than mine, that would then break because both packages are installed. Now thinking that setting up a virtual env might be the way

Comment: There's no good way to manage this IMO. Both projects are installing the `rtmidi` package, effectively overwriting each other's sources. You have listed the right package in the documentation - you can additionally mention the other package as possibly conflicting, and warn that installing your tool may break user's environment. Or you can contact the authors of both projects and try to convince them to change the package names :-)

Comment: You could also vendor the `rtmidi` dependency with your code (by copying its code under e.g. `micronux/_vendor/rtmidi`) and either adjust the imports from `rtmidi` to `micronux._vendor.rtmidi`, or adjust the `sys.path` at the start of your tool so `micronux/_vendor` is inserted in `sys.path` at the first position - this way, your private `rtmidi` will be used, no matter what the user has installed. Those are all not nice solutions if you ask me, but meh.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks, the "vendor" way sounds good and I had thought of something along those lines but because the module has some C code that needs to be compiled I'm not sure how to go about it. Anyway, gonna mention the conflict in my doc then try to convince the project owners to change their module's name (wish me luck :D).

Comment: @wilks I see what you mean, yes, vendoring C extensions will be indeed a hassle. You'd also need to vendor almost the whole contents of `rtmidi`'s setup script in order for the extensions to build correctly.

Comment: @wilks Just as a side comment, having looked at the two packages -- if you can get the functionality from python-rtmidi, you might prefer that one. It looks healthier on PyPI: rtmidi's dev hasn't done a release in 2+ years, and has only that one project on PyPI. python-rtmidi released in October, and its dev is clearly actively working on lots of Python audio projects. Also python-rtmidi looks a lot more lively on pypistats.org. You're less likely to conflict if you use the more popular package.

Comment: @dwhswenson I hear you, those are exactly the reasons why I spent a couple of days coding it for python-rtmidi before realising that pyrtmidi has a some really useful [functions](https://docs.juce.com/master/classMidiMessage.html) that saved me a bunch of time. I might put those as feature requests for python-rtmidi, but ultimately it would be best to have both modules coexisting peacefully, especially since the MIDI specs are the most stable thing I can think of :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't have them both installed (if relying on default `pip` behavior). Here I'll demonstrate with a couple simple pure-Python packages that have an import-name conflict: `coveralls` and `python-coveralls`.

```sh
# in a fresh environment
pip install python-coveralls
python -c "import coveralls; print(dir(coveralls)); print(coveralls.__file__)"
# ['__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__classifiers__', '__copyright__', 
# '__doc__', '__docformat__', '__file__', '__license__', '__loader__', '__name__', 
# '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'parse_args', 'wear']
# /path/to/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coveralls/__init__.py
```

These are the contents of `python-coveralls`. Note that the actual `__init__.py` file is located in the `site-packages/coveralls/` directory.

```sh
pip install coveralls
python -c "import coveralls; print(dir(coveralls)); print(coveralls.__file__)"
# ['Coveralls', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', 
# '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 
# 'api', 'exception', 'git', 'reporter', 'version']
# /path/to/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coveralls/__init__.py
```

These are the contents of `coveralls`. `python-coveralls` has been overwritten. Note that this is the *same* file. Anything in the old `__init__.py` is gone.

```sh
pip uninstall coveralls
python -c "import coveralls; print(dir(coveralls)); print(coveralls.__file__)"
# ['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 
# '__spec__']
# None
```

There's still a ghost of the package there, but its contents are gone (except things that all packages have internally). Notice that the file is now `None`: there is no `__init__.py` file for this package.

You can un-bork your environment by also running `pip uninstall python-coveralls` and then reinstalling whichever you want.

### Solution

You *do* have to require that your users only use the package that is in your requirements, but that's why we use virtual environments. Alternatively, a user that wants to directly use the other package can change the install location (and thus the name used when loading) with the [`--target` option to `pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532112/how-to-handle-python-packages-with-conflicting-names) (but that won't help other apps that use the other library).

In practice, it's probably best to think of this as part of your installation process. You either need to (a) tell your users what requirements they need to install; or (b) have some automated process that gets the right requirements.

I'd say best practice is (b). A common way of doing this is to use `setuptools`, and defining the `install_requires` argument to the `setup` function. This refers to the package name on PyPI, not the import name. [The setuptools quickstart](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: So how does `install_requires=["coveralls"]` help when the user already has `python-coveralls` installed?

Comment: @hoefling Good point -- it will help the developer of the last package installed, but the overall issue remains. Your comment RE: vendoring on the main post is definitely a good option.

Comment: Nice breakdown as to why I was wrong in thinking it was about which module to load when in fact they overwrite each other! You mention virtual env briefly, I'm starting to think it might be a good way around the problem and can't see what the cons would be. Gonna test that and see if it works.

Comment: Realised virtual env wasn't such a great idea. Ended up mixing your answer with @hoefling comments and that worked. Posted it as an answer cos I thought the example code added something, but thanks to you both for getting me on the right track

Answer (score 1):

The following is based on the comments by **hoefling** and the answer by **dwhswenson** (the latter explains well what the problem is).

1. **Flag it to the project owners** so they change the names of their modules. In theory this is by far the best solution as not only it will solve your problem but also save others from it, which is in the best interest of the module's devs. In practice it opens a whole can of worms as to which one should change name.
2. **Or include the module in your project**, aka vendoring, and import it using the path `my_project/_vendor/the_module` (or add that path first in `sys.path`). If the module is just a .py file and the license permits it, this is the simplest way to resolve the issue. This wasn't doable in my case because the module I needed includes some C code that needs to be compiled, and including the whole source code then requiring the user to compile it seemed like big ask. So I had to do this:
3. **Or tell the user to install the module in your project's folder.** Using `pip` with the option `--target` followed by a folder path inside your project, you can get your own copy of the module which won't overwrite the system one. You can then check if that folder exists before importing. If it does, import the module from there, if not you can check if the system-installed module is the right one, and prompt the user if it isn't.

And here's a rough example of how I implemented the code in my project. It replaces `import rtmidi`

```
if os.path.isdir('my_project/rtmidi'):
    from .rtmidi.rtmidi import _rtmidi as rtmidi
else:
    try:
        import rtmidi
    except ImportError:
        print('Please run: pip3 install rtmidi')
        exit()
    try:
        # something that only works with the right module:
        test = rtmidi.MidiMessage() 
    except:
        print('Please run: pip3 install --target=./my_project/rtmidi rtmidi')
        exit()
```

*Note: I should probably just `try` to import the local folder module instead of using a conditional statement, and use the path `my_project/_vendor/rtmidi`.*

Answer (score 0):

i think you should see which one you dont want and delete it then try importing it again.
you can find packages in site-packages folder.

Answer (score -2):

If package names are different import it with package name if are the same you can change package name

Comment: can you be more precise, like how to import with package name and how to change the name of a pip-installed package?

Comment: For example you using command "pip install Wrencher" but if you find folder Wrencher you can see that name of package(folder with code in library folder) is Wrench,so you can try to rename package(folder with code)